# Intersect multiple polygons using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, intersection

I work in the plantation sector, and I use Google Earth Engine to detect sugarcane objects with the NDVI and NDWI algorithms. In doing this analysis I used almost a thousand polygon plots, but there was a problem when I wanted to intersect NDVI and NDWI results in vector format, namely "User memory limit exceeded"

How can fix it?

Here is the GEE link I used:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/9084dc28826c0926b2bfb0bcf8464c56?hideCode=true

```js
//==========================SECTION 1-ADD AREA======================================
var AOI_kebun2 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/pmmbptpn10/batas_kebun2');
Map.centerObject(geometry3,14); 
//========================SECTION 2- ADDED SENTIEL IMAGE 2A=================================
var sentinel2A = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                .filterDate('2021-05-09', '2021-05-15') 
                .filterBounds(geometry);
var Sentinel2  = sentinel2A.mosaic()
                .clip(geometry);   
//===============SECTION 3-ADDED NDVI, AND NDWI ALGORITHM==============================
//NDWI
var NDWI = Sentinel2.expression('(Green-NIR)/(Green+NIR)',{
          'Green': Sentinel2.select('B3'),
          'NIR': Sentinel2.select('B8')
          }); 
//NDVI
var NDVI = Sentinel2.expression('(NIR-Red)/(NIR+Red)',{
         'NIR': Sentinel2.select('B8'),
         'Red': Sentinel2.select('B4')
          });        
//============================SECTION 4-RECLASSIFY=================================================          
//NDVI 
var NDVIrec = ee.Image(NDVI.gt(-1).and(NDVI.lte(0.05)), 1)
          .where(NDVI.gt(0.05).and(NDVI.lte(0.25)), 2)
          .where(NDVI.gt(0.25).and(NDVI.lte(0.74)), 3)
          .where(NDVI.gt(0.74).and(NDVI.lte(1)), 4);
NDVIrec   =NDVIrec.clip(AOI_kebun2);  
//NDWI          
var NDWIrec = ee.Image(NDWI.gt(-1).and(NDWI.lte(-0.65)), 1)
           .where(NDWI.gt(-0.65).and(NDWI.lte(-0.435)), 2)
           .where(NDWI.gt(-0.435).and(NDWI.lte(0)), 3)
           .where(NDWI.gt(0).and(NDWI.lte(1)), 4);
NDWIrec    =NDWIrec.clip(AOI_kebun2);
//=========================SECTION 5-RASTER TO POLIGON=====================================
//5.1 NDVI
var NDVI4 = NDVIrec.reduceToVectors({reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), scale: 10,
            geometry : geometry, maxPixels: 1e9});
NDVI4     = ee.FeatureCollection(NDVI4);
//5.2 NDWI
var NDWI4 = NDWIrec.reduceToVectors({reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), scale: 10,
            geometry : geometry, maxPixels: 1e9});
NDWI4     = ee.FeatureCollection(NDWI4);
//=========================SECTION 7-INTERSECTION=====================================
var vectorList = NDVI4.toList(NDVI4.size());
var polyIntersect = NDWI4.iterate(function(feature, list){
  list = ee.List(list);
  feature = ee.Feature(feature);
  var intersection = vectorList.map(function(feat) {
    feat = ee.Feature(feat);
    var intersection = feat.intersection(feature, ee.ErrorMargin(1));
    return ee.Feature(intersection).set({'Intersect': intersection.area(), maxPixels: 1e15});
  });
  return list.add(intersection);
}, ee.List([])); 
polyIntersect = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(polyIntersect).flatten());
Map.addLayer(polyIntersect,{}, 'Intersection NDVI and NDWI');
```

Comment: Do you need it specifically to be in vector format? If not, you can create a raster image where you calculate NDVIrec.multiply(10).add(NDWIrec), you get a raster with 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, etc. values which match a given NDVI/NDWI combination. You can then filter the areas you are interested in and then reduce to vectors, if you need. Otherwise keep the raster format.